# Make a backport for a 32 bit system using prevu on a 64 bit system

Tags: 64-bit, packaging, 32-bit, backport

I want to make a backport of a package (in my case luakit) on my 64 bit machine (ubuntu natty) for a 32 bit machine (ubuntu jaunty) using [prevu](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Prevu).

What are the detailed steps to do this?

Comment: fork there repo and start compiling and debugging? http://luakit.org/projects/luakit/repository

Comment: Don't forget that jaunty is well past end of life: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases

Answer (score 2):

`prevu` isn't the recommended tool for backports (it's largely unmaintained).

We use the `backportpackage` tool in `ubuntu-dev-tools`. You can either do the build in a PPA or on your machine, using `pbuilder-dist` / `pbuilder` / `sbuild`.

For a PPA, it'd look something like this:

```
$ backportpackage -u ppa:YOURUSERNAME/YOURPPANAME THEPACKGE
```

Of course, many packages aren't automatically backportable, and will need modifications. But for the ones that are, this will work.

Comment: Thanks. Howto backport a 32 bit package using a 64 bit system?

Comment: If you are building on launchpad, it'll build on all architectures. If you are building locally, all of the building tools I suggested can build for i386 on an amd64 machine.

Comment: I get the following error:  dpkg-source --before-build luakit-natty
 fakeroot debian/rules clean
/usr/bin/fakeroot: line 176: debian/rules: Permission denied
dpkg-buildpackage: error: fakeroot debian/rules clean gave error exit status 126
debuild: fatal error at line 1335:
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -d -us -uc -S -sa failed
backportpackage: Error: debuild returned 29.

Comment: Yeah, this package is a bit unusual, in that it needs all its build dependencies installed on the machine you are doing teh backporting on. `apt-get build-dep luakit`

Comment: I get the same error after doing `apt-get build-dep luakit`

Comment: they probably changed between the distro you are using, and the one you are backporting from. For backporting the version in precise (the command I gave) install `liblua5.1-0-dev libgtk2.0-dev libwebkitgtk-dev help2man lua5.1 libsqlite3-dev libunique-dev`. (FWIW, I've just changed backportpackage to get around this requirement, the latest version in the ubuntu-dev-tools PPA will be able to backport this package without the build-dependencies)